# Adding dictionary values as a list of strings

Tags: c#, selenium, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary where the values are stored as a list of strings that I can iterate over. The end goal being something I can mix and match values for passing into parameters in the method, for different Selenium tests.  Basically, the Dictionary is for storing test data.

```
  public void EnterSearchInfo (string username, string cropname, string stationname, string applicationname)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> searchValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    searchValues.Add("User", ["USER1", "USER2"]);
    searchValues.Add("Crop", ["Corn", "Soy"]);
    searchValues.Add("Station", ["AA", "JH", "HW"]);


    _driver.FindElement(user).SendKeys(username);
    _driver.FindElement(crop).SendKeys(cropname);
    _driver.FindElement(station).SendKeys(stationname);
    _driver.FindElement(application).SendKeys(applicationname);
    _driver.FindElement(findAssocBtn).Click();
}
```

The above is not working however, specifically this piece (I am not adding the values correctly):

```
searchValues.Add("User", ["USER1", "USER2"]);
searchValues.Add("Crop", ["Corn", "Soy"]);
searchValues.Add("Station", ["AA", "JH", "HW"]);
```

Any ideas?  Or if there is a better way to handle this, please let me know

Comment: searchValues.Add("User", new List<string>()  {"USER1", "USER2"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the instantiation for each list element of the dictionary.
If you know the values at the time of dictionary creation you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> searchValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "User", new List<string>() {"USER1", "USER2" } },
    { "Crop", new List<string>() {"Corn", "Soy" } },
    { "Station", new List<string>() {"AA", "JH", "HW" } }
};
```

Alternatively, if your values are unknown at time of dictionary creation i.e. when values are retrieved from a text file or database, you can use the Add method from List class.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> searchValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
searchValues.Add("User", new List<string>() { "USER1", "USER2" });
searchValues.Add("Crop", new List<string>() { "Corn", "Soy" });
searchValues.Add("Station", new List<string>() { "AA", "JH", "HW" });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for `GenerareSetLitere`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Piese>> SetPiese = new Dictionary<string, List<Piese>>
{
    { "User", GenerareSetLitere("USER1", "USER2") },
    { "Crop", GenerareSetLitere("Corn", "Soy") }
    { "Station", GenerareSetLitere("AA", "JH", "HW") }
};
```